# set chrome options with remote driver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So there's a nice [long list of switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that can be passed to the chromedriver.

I would like to use some of them, specifically `--disable-logging`.

I do no want to (only) use chromedriver locally though, I'd like to write all my code to use  `webdriver.Remote()`.

Here's the code I use to setup a chrome driver and it works great for a vanilla chrome instance.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor = 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities = {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
    }
)
```

However I can not figure out how to pass in additional options.

When I look at `driver.capabilities` I see the following

```
{
    u'rotatable': False,
    u'browserConnectionEnabled': False,
    u'acceptSslCerts': False,
    u'cssSelectorsEnabled': True,
    u'javascriptEnabled': True,
    u'nativeEvents': True,
    u'databaseEnabled': False,
    u'chrome.chromedriverVersion': u'23.0.1240.0',
    u'locationContextEnabled': False,
    u'takesScreenshot': True,
    u'platform': u'MAC',
    u'browserName': u'chrome',
    u'webdriver.remote.sessionid': u'1352096075502',
    u'version': u'22.0.1229.94',
    u'applicationCacheEnabled': False,
    u'webStorageEnabled': True,
    u'handlesAlerts': True,
    u'chrome.nativeEvents': False
}
```

I don't [see any other arguments](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) (besides `desired_capabilities`) for passing arguments to chromedriver through `webdriver.Remote`. Is this true? Am I missing something? Is there some other strategy for customizing chromedriver?

There's a nice example on the CromeDrive wiki page that shows ["Starting Chromium with Specific Flags"](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) however all the example are for `webdriver.Chrome()`; the example is in java too, so it might not even work in python.

If anyone has gotten this to work or can tell me this just will not work I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

**New Problem**

I'm not sure the best way to handle follow up questions.

So, I got the answer to my question, but I'm still having trouble turning off logging. Checkout the following logger line.

```
[0.455][INFO]:      Launching chrome: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --enable-logging --log-level=1 --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --dom-automation --full-memory-crash-report --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-background-networking --disable-sync --disable-translate --disable-web-resources --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --use-mock-keychain --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-logging about:blank
```

I can pass the argument `--disable-logging` to chromedriver but all it seems to care about is the first argument enabling logging. I guess I need to find out where the default arguments are for new instances of Chrome are kept.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should give you the flags available:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# set some options
# for example:
# options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

Comment: Looks like you would need to do `options.add_argument('--disable-logging').

Comment: @ Nathan Villaescusa -- yes, i will add an example to illustrate. thanks.

Comment: This will result in `desired_capabilities` being `{"chromeOptions": {"args":['--disable-logging']}}`, which is different from my answer. It'll be interesting to see which one ends up working.

Comment: This works (for passing additional arguments), thanks a lot. I'm running into a new problem though.

Answer (score 6):

Just my two cents on this since the selenium remote and chrome webdrivers changed.

```python
import os
from selenium import webdriver


class RemoteBrowser:

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('whitelisted-ips')
    chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1200x800')

    def __init__(self):
        self.hub_url = os.environ['HUB_URL']
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://' + self.hub_url + '/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities = {'browserName': 'chrome'},
            options=self.chrome_options
        )
```

Comment: Confirmed working on selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar and ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.100. Other answers did not work.

Answer (score 2):

From the source code it looks like the only way this would be possible is to pass it through `desired_capabilities`. This dictionary is [sent directly to the remove driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#105) via a POST request.

After looking at how to start chromium with specific flags, maybe something like this would work:

```
desired_capabilities = {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chrome.switches': ['--disable-logging']
}
```

Comment: btw, this also works, I like using `webdriver.ChromeOptions()` more though, seems a little cleaner and more explicit.

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably use that approach as well.

Comment: (Realizing it's been several years...)   This didn't work for me.  Instead, this error after passing the capability dictionary (as parameter to webdriver.Remote()) with an array in it:  "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not convert Array to String."

Answer (score -1):

ChromeOptions() that works for passing additional arguments. try this to disable chromedriver.log

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path='/dev/null')
```

Comment: This is not using "remote" webdriver